# How to number the ToC?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

I need to give a Roman number to the ToC. So basically, I want the ToC to internally use `\chapter` instead of `\chapter*.` Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could temporarily change the meaning of `\chapter*`:

```
\let\stdchapter\chapter
\def\chapter*#1{\stdchapter[\contentsname]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\tableofcontents
\let\chapter\stdchapter
```

I used `\contentsname` for the optional argument to `\stdchapter` because the argument #1 might contain mark commands for the headings, for example `\@mkboth`. That's no problem for the starred command, but if you would use an unstarred command without the optional argument, the mark command would be put into the TOC line as well.