# How can I create a bibliography like a section?

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, numbering, multicol

I have the following:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{multicol}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{multicols}{2}

 \section{}
 \begin{thebibliography}{99}

 \subsection{Differentiation}

 \bibitem{DifIntWiki}
   \emph{URL}

 \end{thebibliography}
 \end{multicols}
 \end{document}
```

It creates a section with a number, and the Bibliography follows on the next line.  I'm interested in combining these two lines together, essentially turning the bibliography into a section.  Is there any way to do this?

Additionally, I'm using the `multicol` package, so I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without affecting the columns.

Comment: It's very similar to the question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6637/how-to-number-the-toc the solution there might be used, just with `\section` instead of `\chapter`. Or use the `tocbibind` package.

Comment: @Stefan: To adapt the answer you pointed to, one would also have to know about `\refname`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\section}{}{}
```

and remove `\section{}` in the text.

I'm not sure if using the `\subsection` command within the `thebibliography` environment causes adverse effects. Also, please clarify "without affecting the columns".

Comment: I'm displaying the bibliography in two columns.  I don't want to affect this setup at all; it currently displays everything correctly in two columns.  The only change I want is to basically combine the two lines I mention.

Comment: @Matt: If the bibliography heading should be part of the first column, then my hack will suffice. But see Stefan's comment - especially consider to use a package like `tocbibind`.